# Cannot connect to Mysql database using Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am running the following code on a Windows Server box using Java on Eclipse.

```
Connection conn = null; // connection object  
Statement stmt = null; // statement object  
ResultSet rs = null; // result set object  
try{  
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/errorcodes", "myusername", "mypassword");   
  System.out.println ("Database connection established");  
 }catch (Exception e){  
  System.err.println ("Cannot connect to database server");  
}
```

And i keep seeing the "Cannot connect to database server error". Any ideas what i might be doing wrong?
I have tried netstat -an and i see :
TCP   127.0.0.1:4464   127.0.0.1:3306    Established

Comment: Can you print out a stack trace of the exception?  Replace "System.err.println(...)" with e.printStackTrace();

Comment: Are you sure the password and login are correct and can see that DB?

Comment: add this to your catch `e.printStackTrace();'

Comment: Try putting the Class.forName statement and the DriverManager.getConnection statement in different try clauses, to see if you're able to load the Driver.

Comment: I added the e.printStackTrace. And added the connector jar. Now I see: Cannot connect to database server java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'myusername'@'localhost' (using password: NO) at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073) and so on.   How do i cross check my sql username? I know my password is correct. And why does it say "using password: NO) ?

Comment: Looks like username was root and not what i had provided when i installed mysql. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess? You haven't got the mysql jdbc connector jar in your classpath. It should be called something like mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar, depending on your version of mysql

If you don't have that jar, visit [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j)

Comment: Thanks, I just did this and added to jar to my project. Now I see: Cannot connect to database server
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'myusername'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)  and so on.

Comment: Then your database credentials or access privileges are incorrect if database server is running. Don't catch all exceptions, or elaborate them with more than one `catch` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you sure that it is mysql running on port 3306 and that it's version is supported by your connector/j?

Comment: I am running MySQL 5.5 and my connector is 5.1.16. Both are the latest.

Answer (score 0):

i think you did not start the MySql server in your PC.before running your application

Answer (score 0):

Try the followings:

1. Clean and rebuild the project in eclipse.
2. Try to access the mysql database using the username and password in command prompt to ensure the username and password are correct.

If you want to ensure the username and password , you have to query the user table in mysql table again to need another mysql admin account to query.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple .. you need .jar file called  mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar ,,, download it and add it to your libs ...

good luck !!!